# simpleModal - ie8 - how to display google map

Tags: iframe, simplemodal

i use jquery simplemodal script to display a google map. but under IE8, doesn't display
http://www.hotel-brasilia-riviera.com/v2/
In Contact window, google map button

thanks for idea